# Round parentheses in math mode when using kpfonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations, parentheses, sqrt

I am trying to write a simple equation that contains fractions, square roots and parentheses. However the output is ugly I'd say

[image]

I tried reducing the space on the nominator using a user-defined command (`\fixit`) but it doens't do the trick.

The problem seems to be the `kpfonts`, but I have to use old style fonts without using `XeLaTeX`.

Any idea on how to make the parenthesis appear more circular?

A simple code can be seen bellow

```
\documentclass{book}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Fonts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Math ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% To remove blank spaces when using \left( and \right)
\newcommand\fixit[4][\displaystyle]{
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#3$}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\vcenter{\copy0}$}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2}{$#1\left#2\copy2\right#4$}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{tc}\right)^2}}-1\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\fixit{(}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{tc}\right)^2}}-1}{)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you committed to using the `kpfonts` package, or could you employ other (math) font packages as well?

Comment: @Mico I had a feeling it was due to that... I will use it because I want an oldstyle package and avoid `XeLaTeX` at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

I think the `\fixit` positioning with displaced brackets looks a bit odd, `\left\right` often selects over-sized delimiters and here it's even more reason to choose them manually to avoid using the form with the straight extension section.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Fonts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Math ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\,\biggl(\sqrt{1-\bigl(\frac{L}{tc}\bigr)^2}-1\biggr)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that `\bigl` and `\bigr` don't look well when the square root is in a fraction. https://imgur.com/StZjbSM So any idea how to make it rounder and still be able to fully cover the vertical dimension?

Comment: @Thanos as i showed you can go bigger than `\bigl`  the `\biggl` in my answer is still round, It is a choice of the font designer how many "designed" parenthesis to put in the font before switching to a form that extends to arbitrary size with a straight extension piece. tex has no control over that at all. So by choosing kpfonts you chose the point at which the change occurs.

Answer (score 1):

(rewrote answer after receiving information that using the `kpfonts` package is essential)

AFAICT, the only way to make the tall parentheses "rounder", when using the `kpfonts` package, is to make the tall parentheses *less tall*. In the present case, I suggest replacing the `\frac` term in the denominator with an inline-fraction expression and replacing `\sqrt{...}` with `\{ ... \}^{1/2}`. That way, the denominator and hence the overall fraction expression as well become much less tall, implying that the surrounding parentheses can be made less tall -- and hence automatically "more round".

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright} \mleftright
% To remove blank spaces when using \left( and \right)
\newcommand\fixit[4][\displaystyle]{
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#3$}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\vcenter{\copy0}$}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2}{$#1\left#2\copy2\right#4$}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
E&=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{tc}\right)^2}}-1\right)\\
E&=mc^2\fixit{(}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{L}{tc}\right)^2}}-1}{)}\\
E&=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\{1-[L/(tc)]^2\}^{1/2}}-1\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I have to stick with kpfonts..

Comment: @Thanos - I've revised my answer thoroughly.

Comment: Just a not on kpfonts (which I use a lot myself), IMO the jump between ( and `\bigl(` is quite noticeable and too large, I've mentioned it to the maintainer who does not have the time to fix it.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for the updated answer. Indeed the parentheses are rounded, but I think the fraction is required. As it is now it looks a bit weird. I guess there is no way to meet all...